# WKWebView not filling container view

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

For some reason my web view is only filling a portion of the container view, even though it is instantiated with `frame: self.webViewContainer.bounds`.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit    

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, {

    @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.webViewContainer.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17"
        let urlString = "http://www.myURL.com"
        if let url = URL(string: encoded!) {
            print(url)
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: The container view's bounds are not the onscreen bounds in `loadView`. You need to wait for `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thank you! I've accepted @Sh_Kahn 's answer along the same lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to set the frame here

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  webView.frame = self.webViewContainer.bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this.

```
webview.sizeToFit()
```